# set the size of a string object

Tags: c++

Need to read some data directly into a string and pass it to other functions. But I don't know how to set the size after copying data into it.

```
string s;
s.reserve(10000);
int n = recv(sock, s.c_str(), 10000);
//how to set the s to have size/length n?
proc(s);
```

I understand that I can allocate a buf of 10000 bytes and save data to it and then create a string object from the buf, but it's not as efficient.

**UPDATE1**
This question is about the difference of methods reserve() or resize(). This is about using a string with enough space as a buffer to store some bytes from, say, network socket.

**UPDATE2**

I just need to make the following code snippet work. Of course, the `s.resize(n)` will zero out the content written into the space reserved for this string object. Need a way to get it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string s;
    s.reserve(100);
    int n = sprintf((char*)(s.c_str()), "hello %f\n", 45.32);
    printf("n=%d\n", n);
    s.resize(n);
    printf("%s\n", s.c_str()); //expect to print hello 45.32
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE3**

Doing `resize()` may work sometimes, but not working always.
As the following code snippet shows, the second printf() should have printed 25 characters, but it only printed 16.
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string s;
    s.resize(20);
    int n = sprintf((char*)(s.c_str()), "helo %f\n", 45.32);
    printf("n=%d\n", n);
    //s.length = n;
    s.resize(n);
    printf("%ld %p %s\n",  s.size(), s.data(), s.data());
    n = sprintf((char*)(s.c_str()), "hello world!!! %f\n", 45.32);
    printf("n=%d\n", n);
    s.resize(n);
    printf("%ld %p %s\n",  s.size(), s.data(), s.data());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are calling `reserve` when what you really want is `resize`.

Comment: Hi @alan-stokes and david-schwartz, my question is different.  I want tto preallocate enough space to a string object and put bytes directly into it and then set the size.

Comment: The method you're using to receive the string is wrong in the first place. Currently you have no way to determine the length of the received string at all. ... Send the size before you send the string, and get rid of constants like 10000, and understand that one send does not map to one receive (you need a loop).

Comment: @deviantfan, the `recv(...)` will return the number of bytes received, it just needs a buffer to keep the data.  I think it would be pity if the famous string class doesn't have a way to set the data size after data is put there.

Comment: You can reduce the size again via another call to `resize`.

Comment: Thanks @AlanStokes for the comment, the problem with `resize()` is that it will think my current string size to be 0 and rewrite the bytes I just received with null bytes.

Comment: That's why you have to start with `resize` not `reserve`.

Comment: @codingFun But you have no guaratnee that this is the whole string, or it could be even more than the string.

Comment: @alan-stokes, I do `reserve()` before I need a buf that's at least 10000 byte for the `recv()` call.  `reserve()` will reserve a buffer of certain size, `resize()` will change the data within the buffer to certain size by triming or appending bytes, which I don't need.  

deviantfan, not sure what you mean by "whole string".  I treat the string as a buffer, so I can store some data and set the size.  After setting the size of the string, I can pass the string object to another function.
Thanks.

Comment: Sigh. From the duplicated answer: "Isn't that the point to reserve() size so you can access it? No, that's the point of resize()." You aren't allowed to access the space reserved; you are allowed to access the string's data if you resize it big enough first.

Comment: And what I meant about the recv part: The other side sends a string, and I guess you want to receive exactly that string, right? You do not want only a part of the string, and you do no want more than the original string while losing data in the next recv. So, you need to check the return value (how many bytes you got), because it could be anything: send calls don't map to recv calls 1:1. You could get less than your wanted string, then you need to call recv again ... loop until you have enough. Or you could get more, then you need to store the rest somewhere for later.

Comment: ...and for doing this, you need to know the string length right from the beginning. That means you need to send the length before you send the string. (And for this, you need to think about endianess, int sizes, etc. ... Sockets are not easy).

Comment: @deviantfan, thanks for the details. I have been socket programming in C. What's needed is (logically) very simple:  need a C++ string object with enough space, dump some bytes in the space by `recv()` and set the size of the string.  I am surprised that it can't be done!

Comment: @alan-stokes, you are right that it's not a conventional use case of the string class, but my use case requires me to dump  some bytes in the space reserved in the string object and then set the size of the string object based on the data dump (in this case `recv(..)`).

Comment: @codingFun As said/omplied, the socket won't tell you where string ends, if you send only the content of it. (TCP) sockets are byte streams which do not know about objects and where they begin/end. That's not a problem of the string class etc. ... Sure it "can" be done, but not your way.

Comment: @deviantfan, I don't need to know what where string ends in a socket. Had been doing socket programming for year.  Here just want to use the reserved space in string object to call `recv()` (this function needs a pointer to buffer).

Comment: Ok, then I have another problem for you: `c_str()` is a `const` function. Casting the const away and writing to it is UB. Use `data()`

Comment: If you replace `reserve` with `resize` in your snippet it will work. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @deviantfan, thanks for the tip, I like the `data()` method!

Comment: @AlanStokes, yes, I can change the `reserve` with `resize` and the 16 bytes from `sprintf` is in the space. However, the string object has a size `100` which is not right, there are only 16 bytes actual data.

Comment: And the second resize fixes that.

Comment: @AlanStokes, that's right,  if I do a `resize(n)` after the sprintf, it will fix it, however, if you do multiple such operation, it will not be wrong, updating the post with UPDATE3.

Comment: You've spent several days now disregarding everything I've said. Best of luck, I'm out.

Comment: @AlanStokes,  It appears you still don't understand what's needed. Could you get the (non-working) code snippet in update3 working?